# How to add values from certain lines of a file together and then deleting a number?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am trying to create a bash script that will provide me with the total number of atoms at the beginning of the file, while also deleting the second count of atoms. However I am unsure how to go about it, since I can't go by column and the line the second value is can vary. Any tips would be much appreciated. An example for this set of molecules would be great too.
Thank you in advance.

For example:

```
18
     H           -1.246549   -3.377143   -1.800000
     C           -0.707293   -2.432587   -1.800000
     C           -1.403477   -1.241616   -1.800000
     C            0.707293   -2.432587   -1.800000
     C           -0.716360    0.000000   -1.800000
     H           -2.492687   -1.240767   -1.800000
     C            1.403477   -1.241616   -1.800000
     H            1.246549   -3.377143   -1.800000
     C            0.716360    0.000000   -1.800000
     C           -1.403477    1.241616   -1.800000
     H            2.492687   -1.240767   -1.800000
     C            1.403477    1.241616   -1.800000
     H           -2.492687    1.240767   -1.800000
     C           -0.707293    2.432587   -1.800000
     C            0.707293    2.432587   -1.800000
     H            2.492687    1.240767   -1.800000
     H           -1.246549    3.377143   -1.800000
     H            1.246549    3.377143   -1.800000
17
     C           -2.432587    0.707293    1.800000
     C           -1.241616    1.403477    1.800000
     C            0.000000    0.716360    1.800000
     C            0.000000   -0.716360    1.800000
     C           -1.241616   -1.403477    1.800000
     C           -2.432587   -0.707293    1.800000
     H            1.240767    2.492687    1.800000
     H           -3.377143    1.246549    1.800000
     H           -1.240767    2.492687    1.800000
     C            1.241616    1.403477    1.800000
     C            1.241616   -1.403477    1.800000
     H           -1.240767   -2.492687    1.800000
     H           -3.377143   -1.246549    1.800000
     C            2.432587   -0.707293    1.800000
     C            2.432587    0.707293    1.800000
     H            1.240767   -2.492687    1.800000
     H            3.377143   -1.246549    1.800000
```

To turn that previous file into a file like what I have shown below by adding the sum of the atoms together, while also deleting the second number.

```
35
18
     H           -1.246549   -3.377143   -1.800000
     C           -0.707293   -2.432587   -1.800000
     C           -1.403477   -1.241616   -1.800000
     C            0.707293   -2.432587   -1.800000
     C           -0.716360    0.000000   -1.800000
     H           -2.492687   -1.240767   -1.800000
     C            1.403477   -1.241616   -1.800000
     H            1.246549   -3.377143   -1.800000
     C            0.716360    0.000000   -1.800000
     C           -1.403477    1.241616   -1.800000
     H            2.492687   -1.240767   -1.800000
     C            1.403477    1.241616   -1.800000
     H           -2.492687    1.240767   -1.800000
     C           -0.707293    2.432587   -1.800000
     C            0.707293    2.432587   -1.800000
     H            2.492687    1.240767   -1.800000
     H           -1.246549    3.377143   -1.800000
     H            1.246549    3.377143   -1.800000
     C           -2.432587    0.707293    1.800000
     C           -1.241616    1.403477    1.800000
     C            0.000000    0.716360    1.800000
     C            0.000000   -0.716360    1.800000
     C           -1.241616   -1.403477    1.800000
     C           -2.432587   -0.707293    1.800000
     H            1.240767    2.492687    1.800000
     H           -3.377143    1.246549    1.800000
     H           -1.240767    2.492687    1.800000
     C            1.241616    1.403477    1.800000
     C            1.241616   -1.403477    1.800000
     H           -1.240767   -2.492687    1.800000
     H           -3.377143   -1.246549    1.800000
     C            2.432587   -0.707293    1.800000
     C            2.432587    0.707293    1.800000
     H            1.240767   -2.492687    1.800000
     H            3.377143   -1.246549    1.800000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `tac` (print files in reverse) and `awk`

```
tac file | awk '$1~/^[0-9]+$/{sum+=$1; curr=$0; next} {print} END{print curr; print sum}' | tac
```

`$1~/^[0-9]+$/` uses a regular expression (`^[0-9]+$`) to check whether the first column contains a number.

**Update:**

`awk` executes `$1~/^[0-9]+$/{sum+=$1; curr=$0; next} {print}` for every line of your file.

If first column contains a number then `awk` adds up the numbers in variable `sum` and saves current line/row (`$0`) in variable `curr` and stops executing code for current line/row here because of `next`. This means that the `print` command is not executed in this case.

If first column contains no number then only `print` is executed.

A different notation for `$1~/^[0-9]+$/{sum+=$1; curr=$0; next} {print}` is this:

```
{
  if($1~/^[0-9]+$/)
    {sum+=$1; curr=$0}
  else
    {print}
}
```

When the last line of your file is processed, code in `END` section is executed once and `awk` ends afterwards.

---

See: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info

Comment: Could you explain what the "next} {print} END{print curr; print sum}' " does? Since google tells me that next just stops the awk command and "Awk will execute the action(s) specified in END before it actually exits". I am not sure what that means, as in next seems to skip the rest of the command but does END run before the next command?

Comment: I've updated my answer. I hope the explanation helps you.